# Join de tabelas SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com um pequeno problema ao fazer um Join entre duas tabelas no SQL, gostaria de saber se vocês podem me ajudar.

São 2 tabelas **GTM_ITEM_CLASSIFICATION** e **ITEM_REFNUM**, ambas referenciam a tabela **ITEM**, porém através de chaves diferentes. Para a primeira tabela, utiliza-se o campo **GTM_ITEM_GID** e para a segunda tabela, utiliza-se o campo **ITEM_GID**.

O que acontece é que quando existe um `Insert User` chamado "ADMIN" na primeira tabela (GTM_ITEM_GID), eu preciso recuperar na outra tabela qual é o registro correspondente ao ADMIN. Esta segunda tabela, é uma tabela de atributos. Para o tipo de usuários que eu quero, eu necessito usar um filtro de `ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'PC_CODE_APPROVER'`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao aplicar o seguinte `select`,

```
SELECT * FROM GTM_ITEM_CLASSIFICATION G
LEFT JOIN ITEM_REFNUM R 
ON G.GTM_ITEM_GID = R.ITEM_GID 
WHERE G.GTM_ITEM_GID IN ('1','2') 
AND R.ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'PC_CODE_APPROVER'
```

O único registro exibido para mim é o **1**, enquanto eu gostaria que exibisse os **2** registros (o segundo com uma referência nula ao lado).

Vocês sabem se é possível fazer um `select` que retorne todos os registros, e os que não existirem na segunda tabela retornem como nulo para mim?!

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema me parece estar na condição após o `AND`: ela só será verdadeira se houver valores não-nulos nas colunas de `R`. Seu join está correto - não fosse por essa condição, toda linha na primeira tabela que não possuísse correspondente na segunda seria retornada com valores nulos.

Minha primeira sugestão é substituir essa condição por:

```
AND (R.ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'PC_CODE_APPROVER' OR R.ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID IS NULL)
```

Não tenho certeza se isso satisfaz sua lógica, mas não tenho nada melhor a sugerir - afinal, você só pode testar condições na segunda tabela se ela não for nula... (em outras palavras, como você vai saber se o `R.ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID` é `PC_CODE_APPROVER` se não existem linhas em `R` que casem com sua linha em `G`? Essa é uma condição impossível, se é isso mesmo que você busca pare e reveja seus requisitos)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar qualquer condição para que a junção ocorra (no caso, o valor de `ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID`, no `ON` do seu `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM GTM_ITEM_CLASSIFICATION G
LEFT JOIN ITEM_REFNUM R 
    ON G.GTM_ITEM_GID = R.ITEM_GID AND R.ITEM_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'PC_CODE_APPROVER'
WHERE G.GTM_ITEM_GID IN ('1','2')
```